# Chrome Hangouts thingy stuck in sidebar, always opens even if deleted

Tags: 16.04, google-chrome, icons

so I recently got the chrome extension for ubuntu, and it was working properly until now. When I opened google chrome, instead of that icon coming in the sidebar, both chrome's icon AND the hangouts icon are coming up! And even when closing chrome, both the icons close at the same time. I even tried removing the hangouts extension, but it's of no use. Please help! Here is a screenshot of both appearing.[Click here for the screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lc0Iy.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same thing happened to me, and after much frustration, I had checked the folder `~/.local/share/applications`, where all the desktop configuration files reside. The google hangout extension had overwritten the desktop configuration file for google chrome.

Solution to this is just replace the `~/.local/share/applications/google-chrome.desktop` file with the original copy of desktop configuration file from `/usr/share/applications`.

```
cp -t ~/.local/share/applications /usr/share/applications/google-chrome.desktop
```